# Raspberry Pi not booting - red power light, no ACT light

Tags: boot, power-supply, activity-led

I shut my RPi3 Model 3B+ down earlier with `sudo shutdown now`, and while it was shutdown, but not disconnected, we had a power outage. When the power came back on, the Pi would not start.
The red power light is coming on, but the ACT light is not coming on at all.

I think it might be done for - can anyone help?

Comment: try a new SD card with a fresh install of raspberry pi OS

Comment: Bought a new card, formatted it and the pi is back working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fault find see [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

It is possible, but unlikely, that the Pi "might be done for" but it is far more likely that the OS file system is damaged.

I suggest you **restore from your backup**.
It is possible that the SD Card is damaged/worn out but even this is not likely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `e2fsck -f <device>` file system check on the SD card on your PC